# Why are the kernel function names not resolving in the output of kstack()?

Tags: linux-kernel, trace, ebpf, bpftrace

I am trying to see the kernel stack with the following `bpftrace` command:

```
root@ubuntu:~$ bpftrace -e 'k:vfs_read{@[kstack] = count()}'
Attaching 1 probe...
^C

@[
    0xffffffffa78d2dc1
    0xffffffffa78d306a
    0xffffffffa7604fd7
    0xffffffffa82000a4
]: 5
```

What should I do to see kernel function names instead of the addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `/proc/kallsyms`. If the first column is all zeros, it probably means that there are some restrictions placed on exposing kernel addresses. Here's a sample output:

```
root@ubuntu:~# head /proc/kallsyms
0000000000000000 A fixed_percpu_data
0000000000000000 A __per_cpu_start
0000000000000000 A cpu_debug_store
0000000000000000 A irq_stack_backing_store
0000000000000000 A cpu_tss_rw
0000000000000000 A gdt_page
0000000000000000 A exception_stacks
0000000000000000 A entry_stack_storage
0000000000000000 A espfix_waddr
0000000000000000 A espfix_stack
```

The restrictions can be dropped by setting `/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict` to `0` (consider `1` as well to keep some of the protections on):

```
root@ubuntu:~# echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
```

At least in my case, this was enough to get the addresses to resolve to function names in the output of `kstack()`:

```
root@ubuntu:~# bpftrace -e 'k:vfs_read{@[kstack] = count()}'
Attaching 1 probe...
^C

@[
    vfs_read+1
    __x64_sys_read+26
    do_syscall_64+87
    entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+92
]: 2
```

Additional documentation:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html?highlight=kptr_restrict#kptr-restrict